# Using context for a click event bound to a class

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

For an MVC app I'm working on, I have a view that can populate a number of subviews like such:

**Some View Partial**

```
@model SuperFoo

<!-- snip unimportant details... ->

@foreach(var current in Model.Items)
{
    @Html.Partial('_Item', current);
}

<!-- ...SNIP more useless details... -->

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-item').click(function () {
        // Make some AJAX call to do something.
    });
});
</script>
```

**Individual Item Partial**

```
@model Foo

<div class='some-styling'>
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PropA)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PropN)

   <input type='text' value='' />
   <a href='javascript:;' class='no-line add-item'>Add To Cart</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out two things:

**A)** How do I ensure only the specific button I've clicked on fires its event, and

**B)** How do I use information specific to information obtained for a specific item?  If you notice, I've got an editable input field in my item level view.  When a click is triggered, the resulting AJAX call needs to use the value in that text box (which is the easy part, `$('selector').val()`)

I'm using only jQuery and MVC3.  Question (probably a stupid one, but we'll see): How can my individual Add Item links operate using the context of the partial that is rendering them?

Comment: Using editor template instead of partials would likely make more sense here

Comment: Either way, I still need to operate on context.  The vehicle of how the context is presented *shouldn't* matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do realize that after the page is fully rendered there is no segregation such as `partial view` it is just to manage your code, i have not fully grasped your question but ill try

Answer to A

```
$('.add-item).click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();// prevent the default behavior of the anchor
  this; //is your friend, it will give you the DOM element which is clicked
  $(this); // will give you the nicely wrapped jQuery object      
});
```

Answer to B

> How do I use information specific to information obtained for a specific item?

not sure what you are asking here but if you wrap your items like

```
<div class="item-wrap">
  <input type='text' value='10'/>
  <a href=#' class='no-line add-item'>Add To Cart</a>
</div>

<div class="item-wrap">
  <input type='text' value='20'/>
  <a href='#' class='no-line add-item'>Add To Cart</a>
</div>
```

then in the click handler

```
$('.add-item).click(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       var $val = $this.closest(':input').val();
       //will give you 20 or 30 depending upon which one you click

       //or
        var $$val = $this.closest('.item-wrap>:input').val();

      //you can write a variety of selectors which can vary in perf 

    });
```